# Run PHP Artisan Without Change Directory

Tags: php, bash, laravel, laravel-artisan

How to run command php artisan serve without change to the proect directory?

I try to run this command but nothing happen

```
php /home/john/Documents/project/ artisan serve --port=1111
```

I want to insert this command to alisases at bash aliases so i don't need to insert the port anymore.
Please help me, how to run artisan with specified directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to remove space:

```
php /home/john/Documents/project/artisan serve --port=1111
```

Comment: That is because you want to execute the `artisan` file and not a shell command